# Is it possible to use ink! with Ethereum-style accounts?

Tags: account, evm, contracts

Wondering if anyone knows whether ink! supports AccountIds which are ethereum-style accounts? Let's assume this would be a chain with a [Unified Accounts](https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/unified-accounts/) setup, similar to Moonbeam. In specific, we could assume this would be a chain whose runtime's AccountId type comes from a [signature type](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/b917fa7ec9c9c31144ae86a024eea887b0cb59c5/primitives/account/src/lib.rs#L100) also similar to Moonbeam's.

If it is supported, are there any important considerations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wondering if anyone knows whether ink! supports AccountIds which are
> ethereum-style accounts?

Yes. `pallet-contracts` will work with the unified account setup you referenced. It is generic over the `AccountId`. The type is defined chain wide in [`frame_system::pallet::Config`](https://docs.rs/frame-system/20.0.0/frame_system/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.AccountId).

For example, Moonbeam would have no problem integrating `pallet-contracts`. It will just work with their customized `AccountId`.

> If it is supported, are there any important considerations?

While the `AccountId` is generic, it is still rare for chains to actually deviate from the default type. Hence most ink! contracts probably hard code or at least have some assumptions about the used `AccountId`. An ink! contract [needs to be configured](https://use.ink/basics/chain-environment-types) in order to learn about which types a chain uses.

Hence you need to change and re-compile a contract for each target chain that uses a different environment. Changing the contract code in order to compile it for different environments is quite annoying. You could introduce a cargo feature for your contract which would allow you to select different environments when compiling using `--features`.

Like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(TypeInfo))]
#[cfg(feature = "moonbeam")]
pub enum MoonbeamEnvironment {}

#[cfg(feature = "moonbeam")]
impl ink_env::Environment for MoonbeamEnvironment {
    // Configure for moonbeam.
    // `type AccountId` would be the interesting item
}

#[cfg(feature = "moonbeam")]
type MyEnv = MoonbeamEnvironment;

#[cfg(not(feature = "moonbeam"))]
type MyEnv = ink_env::DefaultEnvironment;

#[ink::contract(env = MyEnv)]
```

Comment: Ah thank you - this helps me pre-empt a possible issue

Comment: If you want a single contract to work on chains with different environments you could use cargo features. Added an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ethereum accounts in ink! as long as pallet-contracts is present.

> You can use ink! on any blockchain that was built with the [Substrate](https://substrate.io)
> framework and includes the [`pallet-contracts`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts)
> module.
> Substrate does not define specific types for a blockchain, it uses
> generic types throughout.
> Chains built on Substrate can decide on their own which types they want
> to use for e.g. the chain's block number or account id's. For example,
> chains that intend to be compatible to Ethereum typically use the same
> type as Ethereum for their `AccountId`.

https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/6fb975d77c61bd08c662e2111c4f35b0e50a3d37/ARCHITECTURE.md?plain=1#L194-L202

Edit: I don't believe there any important considerations, it "just works" out of the box.